# Getting Error with RxJs "unrecognized teardown 10 added to Subscription"

Tags: javascript, rxjs, event-loop

I'm trying to make a simple subscription on zero-timeout to execute some code after the event loop will move to the next phase

```
  import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

  const render = () => {
    ...
    return Observable.create(observer =>
      setTimeout(() => {
          observer.next();
          observer.complete();
        })
    );
  };

  ...

  render().subscribe(() => {  ... });
```

This leads to

> ERROR Error: unrecognized teardown 10 added to Subscription.
>       at Subscriber.Subscription.add (Subscription.js:144)
>       ...

If I replace Observable with Promise approach, the code works as expected

```
  const render = () => {
    ...
    return new Promise(resolve =>
      setTimeout(() => resolve())
    );
  };

  ...

  render().then(() => { ... });
```

What's wrong there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're returning the result of the `setTimeout` call when RxJS expects `undefined`, a function or an object with an `unsubscribe` function.

You could fix the problem by adding braces to your arrow function:

```
return Observable.create(observer => {
  setTimeout(() => {
      observer.next();
      observer.complete();
    })
});
```

Comment: I don't understand why adding braces fixes the problem but it worked for me too.

Comment: @gian848396 Without the braces there is an implicit return of what's returned from `setTimeout` and "RxJS expects `undefined`, a function or an object with an `unsubscribe` function." Adding the braces ensures that `undefined` is returned.